# xcodebuild skipping CodeSign step

Tags: ios, xcode4, xcodebuild

I have a project that will build fine from the XCode v4.0.2 gui.  However, when I run it from the command line via xcodebuild:

```
xcodebuild -target MyProj -configuration Release -sdk iphoneos
```

it will run up until ProcessProductPackaging:

```
    CompileC ...
    CompileC ...
    Ld ...
    Ld ...
    CreateUniversalBinary ...
    CreateDSYMFile ...
    ProcessProductPackaging ...

** BUILD SUCCEEDED **
```

In the XCode gui I can see it do these steps, but it also does the CodeSign step.  Why is it being skipped when I run it from the command line?  Isn't xcodebuild supposed to do the same thing as the gui?